# crash on device

Tags: android, database, crash

I have an application of which i have use database to insert values on list view . When I run the app on emulator after merging it runs fine but crashes on the device when values begin inserted  the LogCat shows me the:close cursor but i have already close all coursers that begin opened.
this the button action

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

        tx = txt.getText().toString();
        postive.add(tx);
        if(tx.length() >0)
        {
            myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO UP (ID,UPNAME) VALUES ('"+idnum+"','"+tx+"')");

            txt.setText("");            
            function();
             results.clear();
            Intent i=new  Intent(Positive.this,NewgridActivity.class);
            bundle.putInt("tabid", 1);
            bundle.putInt("id", idnum);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else
            DisplayToast("TextField Empty !!!!");

    }
});
```

any help please.

error in logcat

```
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/pa.gd/databases/DECISION_GRID' 
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at pa.gd.PAIDGRIDActivity.onCreate(PAIDGRIDActivity.java:66)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-21 13:11:02.582: E/Database(4909):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

log error afer closing database

i have close the db when i then try to add i a value it crashes with this log error

```
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1723)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dc.grd.Positive$1.onClick(Positive.java:77)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-21 15:45:58.043: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show logcat error in question

Comment: Pratik i have edit the log cat error

Comment: the error said that you either not close the cursor somewhere or you reopen the database which was already opened check where you open the database and close in your code

Comment: can you say how to close database (i mean the query for closing database)

Comment: You seem to be using `myDB` for your database object. In that case use this to close it: `myDB.close();`.

Comment: i have close the db and then  i then try to add  a value it crashes with this log error i will show you log error in my question

Comment: Sander Vant Veer :: Thank u bro the answer was right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You seem to be using myDB for your database object. In that case use this to close it: myDB.close();. – Sander van't Veer 
>   <

1. myDB.close(); the solution give by Sander Vant Veer worked

Comment: i have open the the database on button click and after inserting the value use myDB.close(); to close my database and it work the crash was cleared in my device

Answer (score 0):

Think about a life cycle for you database connection. I recommend to open the db in your application class or in the `onResume()` method of your activity. Close the db in `onPause()`.

Whenever you work with the database, make sure that all cursors are correctly closed after you are done working with it.

And by the way: Every time you write a question title like you did, a kitten dies...

Comment: thank for you answer...can you say what this log cat error is about?

Comment: one is telling you to close your database/cursor after using it, the second one is telling you that your database is not open. Once again: Think about a life cycle like you have one for your activity...

Comment: i have tried those too.when i run the app in the emulator it still work fine but when runs on the device it crashes but the values is begin inserted successfully after the app get restarted after the crash

Comment: Make some log.d() calls so you see where you open and close the database. You than might see whats happening. Also there is a difference between closing the database and closing the cursor.

Comment: Warren i think it is about the memory management ?what do u think?

Comment: no, it isnt. If you would just do as I recommended, you would get some results...